# Where does my leading zeroes go?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am reading in numbers from a comma seperated textfiles, where some numbers are on the form 000000084. These files are added to a messageclass, and then put in a SQLite database. The problem I have is that SQLite saves these 000000084 as 84, even though I create the table column as a string.

Inputfile

```
something,000000018,213123
somethingelse,000000025,213123
```

Creation of database:

```
def createDatabase(databasepath):
    con = lite.connect(databasepath)
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE staticMessage(userid string)")
```

Message class:

```
class StaticMessage:  
    def __init__ (self, userid):
        self.userid    = userid
```

Extracting message from file:

```
def extractStaticMessages(filepath):
    global staticMessage
    staticMessage = []
    lengths = []
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    for line in f:
        newline = line.split(",")
        message = StaticMessage(newline[1])
        staticMessage.append(message)
```

Writing message to database:

```
def writeStaticToDatabase(databasepath):
    con = lite.connect(databasepath)
    con.isolation_level = None
    with con:
       cur = con.cursor()  
       cur.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')  
       for i in range(0, len(staticMessage)):
           cur.execute("INSERT INTO staticMessage(userid) VALUES(?)", 
            (staticMessage[i].userid)
       cur.execute('COMMIT')
```

When I then query my database with f.ex:

```
select userid from staticMessage where userid='000000084'
```

I get `84`

This is a major annoyance for me, because I want to query my database to get the number of userids less than nine digits.

TL/DR: where does my leading zeros go when inserting into SQLite?

Comment: Just a small note, you should definitely use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read in the values from file, rather than rolling your own. And you can just do `for message in staticMessage:`, no need for the `range` and array indexing. Can you show how you're displaying `84` when you say "I get 84"? It's possible that that could be where the problem is, rather than that the data is being stored in the database itself incorrectly. Have you checked in the raw database tables to see if it's being inserted as `"000000084"`?

Comment: Show the table schema.

Comment: @aruisdante Thank you for your answer. I get 84 by running the query shown right over that. The ubuntu terminal outputs 84. But you are right, it is possible that it is indeed saved as it should, but it is cutted down in the output.

Comment: @ingacio-vazquez-abrams The table schema is shown where I create table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not enforce strong column typing. Instead, SQLite use something called *type affinity*: there is a *prefered* storage type that is derived from your column declaration and some internal rules, but you can very well store text in numeric and vice versa.

The [official documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname) clearly explains the rules that will determine the type used to store the data:

> The affinity of a column is determined by the declared type of the
>   column, according to the following rules in the order shown:
>
> 1. If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned INTEGER affinity.
> 2. If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice
>      that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned
>      TEXT affinity.
> 3. If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no type is specified then the column has affinity NONE.
> 4. If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL", "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
> 5. Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC.
>
> Note that the order of the rules for determining column affinity is
>   important. A column whose declared type is "CHARINT" will match both
>   rules 1 and 2 but the first rule takes precedence and so the column
>   affinity will be INTEGER.

As your column is declared as "string" -- which cannot be derived to one particular type affinity, SQLite will try as far as possible from rule 5 to store your data as numeric. So removing the leading zeros *if the value can be converted to a numeric*.

Please note however that you can store text (say: 'T000000084') without any issue -- as SQLite will not be able to convert that to a numeric (the preferred type affinity), it will store it as text instead.

---

Given our particular need, you should declare your column with *text* affinity. Namely using a type containing the string `CHAR`, `CLOB` or `TEXT` type (rule 2).

Answer (score 1):

`000000084` is not a number, `84` is. You want to store these in a TEXT datafield in SQLite.

Comment: Can't you just cast `int('000000084')`?